# VBA Excel SaveAs xlDBF4

Tags: excel, vba, file-format

StackOverflow community,

I recently have a problem creating this macro below, regarding how to save as xlDBF4 and active workbook from excel. I don't why, but doesn't work appears a run-time error and I already try with the FileFormat:= 11 and FileFormat:= xlDBF4

```
Sub SaveAsDBF()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim strPath As String
            strPath = "C:\"
            strPath = strPath & ActiveSheet.Name & ".dbf"
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strPath, FileFormat:=xlDBF4, _
                CreateBackup:=False
            'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strPath, FileFormat:=11
End Sub
```

Comment: *appears a run-time error* isn't a problem description. What is the exact error message you're seeing?

Comment: Run-time error '1004': Method 'SaveAs' of object '_Workbook' failed

Comment: All xlFileFormat(s) for DBF (2,3 and 4) seem to generate the 1004 error. My subsequent web searches would seem indicate that the ability to save to DBF was deprecated in Excel 2007. Some people have used Access as a intermediary to import Excel data and then save the data in DBF format. Also, there are supposedly Excel addins that can be purchased to do this as well, but I have no experience with them. Can anyone confirm the DBF save was deprecated back then?

Answer (score 0):

If it absolutely has to be a DBF file then the only solution with latest Excel is to use ADODB and execute queries, make sure your office / Excel is 32-bit since the driver for DBF only works in 32-bit.
Reference `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library` code example to execute DBF queries:

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim comm As ADODB.Command
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set comm = New ADODB.Command

conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDB.4.0;Extended Properties=dBASE IV;Data Source=C:\Temp"
comm.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE 201008 ([FirstName] String(50), [LastName] String(50))"
With conn
    .Open
    With comm
        .ActiveConnection = conn
        .Execute
    End With
End With

conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
Set comm = Nothing
```